# Revoked certificates and CRL/Delta CRL

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I'm testing AD CS for an in-house application, but seem to be coming across a particular problem with the CRL/delta CRL.

Basically for testing purposes I am using RDP certificates (which are issued by my CA, not self signed). I have revoked the RDP certificate for a particular server issued by my CA. I've manually published a new CRL/Delta CRL.

On a workstation I then attempt to connect to the serer using RDP and... it just connects straight away, no warnings, nothing to say that the certificate has been revoked.

I confirmed that I can access both the CRL and the delta CRL. Also, I confirmed that the certificate I revoked appears in the revoked list.

Is there an internal CRL cache that the client keeps so that it's not always asking the CA for the newer CRL/delta CRL? If so, where is this located and how can I force the client to re-download the CRL/delta CRL?

**EDIT**

Ok, so I found that using `certutil -urlcache <path> delete` I can delete items from the cache. However, even after deleting the whole cache RDP still seems to think that the certificate is valid - it just connects straight away.

Also, it doesn't seem like it even tries to get a new CRL, as after attempting to connect using RDP the cache remains empty (using `certutil -urlcache` command)

Comment: Could you confirm if the certificate contains the extension  **CRL Distribution Point** with the URL where the CRL is published? I'm not a RDP expert, but I also found this: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2011/04/11/how-to-enable-certificate-revocation-checking-on-a-remote-desktop-gateway-client/ - not sure how relevant it might be

Comment: One way is to wait until old CRL expires. Another is to use OCSP. IMHO it is normal behavior to cache CRL until `Next update` is reached. Deleting CRL on every client each time you want to use RDP is too much effort.

Comment: @Hugo cert does contain the CDP URL - that's all be confirmed.

Comment: @pepo I started looking at OCSP and definitely going to implement it, but even with OCSP you'd still be affected by this. i.e., with OCSP the customer checks its cache to see if it contains a valid OCSP answer (so there's still a cache at the client level) and if the client doesn't contain one it sends a request to OCSP. Then at the OCSP level it also verifies whether there's already a response in the cache (that it sent to another client maybe?) and if not it creates one. Which will be based on CRL of course, but I believe it will be based on cached CRL to begin with? Anyway still gets cached

Comment: @cogumel0 True - OCSP server (at least in MS CA) takes the information from CRL but I think (I did not check) it will use the latest CRL to get the information. It's a valid way of doing things but I would prefer to look in CA certificate database to get the information if I were to implement an OCSP server. OCSP response should be valid for a short time in contrast to CRL validity so it would be a better option.

Comment: @pepo agree. Like I said I will implement OCSP. Despite the fact that with an OCSP this problem will be less widespread, it will still be there and it would be nice to know how to force the client (or server, if using OCSP, since the server uses the CRL to create the OCSP response) to delete its cache.

Comment: `certutil -urlcache * delete` taken from [here](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1353318-delete-crl-and-ocsp-cache)

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. I did finally find something that clearly straight away though: `certutil -setreg chain\ChainCacheResyncFiletime @now` - this automatically invalidates all cached CRLs and forces a resync. This worked straight away unlike the `certutil -urlcache * delete` command.